# Bug does not count upvotes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I noticed that all upvotes (in total four) between 10:28pm and 11:48pm where not counted for my account.

- one question: all upvotes are ignored
- second question: one upvote is ignored

[image]

Comment: unless this can be demonstrated to be a network-wide problem, this bug report should stay here

Comment: @KyleCronin Ok. I'd be nice to get some feedback on bug posts, tough. Otherwise, I have no confirmation that someone responsible has taken a look at it. Something like your commment would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hit the daily reputation cap on that day. From the [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of **200** reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get this :(.  If I can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day, how come I've crossed that maximum already several times before? The posts that did not get any rep for are not wiki posts.

Comment: "accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit" -- the reputation limit mainly refers to reputation *earned from upvotes*

Comment: Ah, sorry! I skipped that part when skimming the text. :)